# Why can't I pass str.indexOf to map in javascript

Tags: javascript

Why can't I do the following?

```
var str = "A string with * and ^ and even $";
var indeces = ["*", "^", "$"].map(str.indexOf); // doesnt work
```

I'd rather not pass in another function to do the exact same thing as the method itself...

```
[...].map(function(token) { return str.indexOf(token); }); // works
```

Is there an elegant way to do this?

Comment: Just a notice : map isn't available for IE8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference between

```
function(token) { return str.indexOf(token); }
```

and

```
str.indexOf
```

is that you wouldn't have context problem in the first case.

In the second case, this would no be `str` but `window`. `str.indexOf` is the value of the property named `indexOf` of the string. It's a function but there is no way from the value to know from which object you took it. So if you pass `str.indexOf`, you're just passing the function, not at all `str`.

```
["*", "^", "$"].map(str.indexOf);
```

would be equivalent to

```
["*", "^", "$"].map(function(token) { return window.indexOf(token); });
```

if there was a indexOf function on window.

Just to try to be clearer, but don't use it : a function *could* be bound to an object. If you do

```
var f = str.indexOf.bind(str); // makes a copy of indexOf, bound to str
["*", "^", "$"].map(f);
```

then `this` is `str` when `f` is called.

Comment: I don't get it though! They both take in the same value. Shouldn't they act similarly if passed to map?

Comment: The difference is the receiver, `this`. `map` call the function with receiver `window` (the default context).

Comment: Ok trying to understand. So the indexOf method doesn't belong to `str`? This is plain old js btw, not jquery

Comment: Yes, this function (which happens to be the same for all strings but that's not really the core problem) is just a function, not a function bound to an object, and `this` isn't the object where you found the function.

Comment: Ah, so I'm passing a reference to the prototype method but it has no way of knowing which string object I wanted to call it on. That does make sense, thanks!

Comment: @dystroy: `[...].map(str.indexOf);` is *NOT* equivalent to `[...].map(function(token) { return window.indexOf(token); });`, but to `[...].map(function(token) { return (null||undefined).indexOf(token); });`

Comment: @Koilnc Read the MDN : " the global object associated with callback is used instead.". In browsers, the global object is window. And don't forget I wrote ("if there was a indexOf function on window.").

Answer (score 1):

For reasons already explained by [@dystroy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/263525/dystroy), you can't do this. You can however use `map` using a context, and that will give the desired result:

```
var str = "A string with * and ^ and even $"
var indeces = ["*", "^", "$"].map( str.indexOf, str);
//                                              ^str is context
//=> indeces = [14, 20, 31]
```